# htaccess and IE8 image not displaying

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am building a website for a friend, we have decided to simply display an image for users of IE8 and below.
I have set up a htaccess. to send anyone using IE8 and below to a different URL.
In this new url it is just going to be a simple image displayed telling people our contact details and that there browser is to old.
I know this is not the best solution but it is a simple fix until we can learn the best way to go about it.

My problem is that when viewing in IE8 or below, the image is not visible. When viewing in IE9 or Chrome it works perfectly.

Any help would be much appreciated, I have included the code I have used below.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 6"  [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 7"  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE 8"  
RewriteRule (.*) IE/index.html
```

I have then used the following   IE/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>
<img src="/IE/comingsoon.png" width="1024" height="768" />



</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it won't be, you're trapping any requests from IE6/7/8 and redirecting them to this page. So when those browsers load this page, parse it, find the image, and try to load that image, the image request gets redirected as well, and they end up trying to use the HTML as an image.

You need to explicitly EXCLUDE anything in your `IE` folder from redirection by those browsers.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^IE
```